# Is the Success of the Solar Energy Policies in Australia the motivation of the carbon tax backlash?

Tags: taxes

I came across this [article](http://reneweconomy.com.au/2014/solar-sends-energy-prices-below-zero-in-middle-of-day-63767) about the spot market energy prices going below zero during the day in NSW for a few days.  This is traditionally the money making time of day for the Coal plant producers.  The article attributes this to the Solar energy polices, which are under attack by the carbon lobby.   It seems to me that the Carbon industries are resorting to political manipulation to preserve their industry for a few more years.  What is another explanation?

Answer (score 3):

Energy sold back to the power companies through solar panels is currently exploiting a lack of fair regulation. Houses with solar panels are all still connected to the grid and rely on the grid to supply power at any time. Maintaining the grid and near 24/7 up time of electricity represents a significant cost for electric companies, that is reflected in the price per KW/h of electricity. In some places companies are forced to buy power at what they sell, which results in solar homes not paying their fair share to maintain the grid they rely on. Solar policies are receiving push back from "big carbon" because they are being implemented without respect to the 30-50 year investments they've made often based on contractual obligations, and now they are seeing the demand being filled by solar that was supposed to be covered by a power plant with 30 more years of life expectancy that hasn't come close to making a return on investment and they are still expected to pay to keep everything running.

The carbon tax push back is more straight forward, its a direct cost to power companies that they are going to pass on to consumers like any other cost increase in any other industry.

Comment: So your answer is kind of?  The power companies are not able to meet their carbon tax obligations because they are being forced to buy more power than they need to supply, which impacts their ability to maintain a working business model.

Comment: My answer is these are two separate issues that both negatively affect power companies. They oppose carbon taxes and solar energy policies for completely different reasons.

Comment: Then maybe you could improve that answer to make that clear

Comment: "fair share" is an oversimplification and arguably energy industry spin.

Comment: Surprisingly insightful answer. Interesting that leasing access to the grid for solar powered homes hasn't(?) offset infrastructure costs.